# Insert tab deliberated string to table, with "FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'"

Tags: php, sql, insert, field

Pretty much all said in the title, I have a string which is an imploded array with values seperated by \t, wondering if there is a way to insert this into a table. I know you can use "FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'" when inserting txt files, and would make sense if it could be used for variables, but

```
mysql_query ("INSERT '".$arri."' INTO TABLE orders_imported FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'", $conn);
```

Doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`fields terminated by` is for use with `load data infile`, not a regular `insert`.

To use an insert, you would have to do something like iterate over the array and use:

```
insert into `TABLE` values (val1, val2, val3 /* ... */)
```

Multiple rows can be inserted efficiently with a single insert statement by using a comma after the end bracket, and then starting another bracket for the next row.

For `load data infile`, you would have to write the string to a file that was either accesible to the server, or use the `local` option if you're MySQL server is configured to allow this.